# Spring test integration not run how I deal with this error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a test class that make me crazy with this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
>   Error creating bean with name .imprimirRelatorio: Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field repository; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:  No
>   qualifying bean of type v1.teste.Service available: expected  at least
>   1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.  Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

After search in the web by a resolution, I couldn't run the test. The test class was like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class imprimirRelatorio {


   @Autowired
   PautaService pautaRepository;

    @Test
    public void imprimirCabecalho(){
        PautaReportBuilder pautaReportBuilder = new PautaReportBuilder();
        //Reuniao reuniao = reuniaoService.findOne(UUID.fromString("4c7d3fc8-f78d-4ed3-a1ad-83c5da822ea7"));


        try {
             pautaReportBuilder.cabecalhoRelatorios(reuniao);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

/* 
Update
*/

So I forgot to say that I already tried the annotation @service in the pautaService interface. And the same on the test class I've  tried to use the @SpringBootTest annotation. So the error messages was different.

The App.class

```
 @SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan({"br.com.empresa123.sistema123.*"}) 
public class App { public static void main(String[] args) { 
SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
 }
 }
```

The interface PautaService:

```
@Service
public interface PautaService {

    Page<Pauta> findAll(Pageable page);

    Pauta findOne(UUID uuid);

    Pauta save(Pauta pauta);
}
```

This is the first approach of my test , the nested exception were :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'subjectController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'subjectService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'subjectService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'domainSvc'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dominio': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'domainRepo'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'domainReposImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'sqlGenericPager'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sql-Generic-Pager)}

Comment: Is your PautaService annotated with @Service and does it implement the `v1.teste.Service`? I believe you'll get similar error when just starting an application. Share more code

Comment: No, the PautaService hasn't the annotation but the PautaServiceImpl has. I tried to annotate the interface PautaService with @Service but still not working.

Answer (score 4):

For integration test, add `@SpringBootTest` over your class.

In case where your file is not in the same packaging of your app, `@ComponentScan()` your app packaging.

Comment: Thanks GabLeg , But I've tried to use the annotation `@SpringBootTest` and a lot of nested exception was threwn . Also my App.class has the `@ComponentScan`  Annotation like that: ```@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"br.com.empresa123.sistema123.*"})
public class App {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: I was talking about adding the `@ComponentScan()` over your class test. Sorry for the confusion. If your test class is under folder `br.com.empresa123.somethingDifferent`, it is normal that your `@SpringBootTest` doesn't not found all your beans because he is trying to find them under `br.com.empresa123.somethingDifferent`. That's why you need to add `@ComponentScan("br.com.empresa123.sistema123")` over your test class. Maybe you could add the stacktrace that comes out when you add `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have forgot to annotate the service with the @Service annotation. If so, please tag the Service **CLASS** with @Service.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem when I search by a annotation lost in my code that I never used it :

```
public abstract class BaseCustomRepository {

    // the class code 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sql-Generic-Pager")
    protected String sqlGenericPager;

}
```

I never used a Custom repository implementation so I will rethink what I will do with this class. Thanks a lot of the coders that lost their time to help me and the stack over flow to share my concerns.

I was laughing about this question, all the trouble was caused by me, like you do a git blame command in a class and see your user that made the wrong code.